# Which life cycle method can I use on a component every time it is re-rendered

Tags: reactjs

I'm actually building a notes app in reactJS. I wrote a function in componentDidMount for one of the components to perform auto resize but whenever I render a new instance of the component from the App.js file, the auto resize no longer works.

This is a portion of the  component but the point of concern here is the 'componentDidMount'. Here I wrote a function that makes sure that a certain textarea in the component resizes automatically.

```
import React from 'react'

class Note extends React.Component{
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {}

    }


    componentDidMount() {
        var text = document.querySelector('.textInput');
        text.addEventListener('input', onInput, false);

        function onInput(e) {
            this.style.height = 'auto'
            this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px'
        }
    }
```

This is the render method in the App.js file. The Note component before the map function resizes automatically in the DOM but whenever the map function executes and renders a new Note component, the auto resize does not work again.

```
 render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <div className = 'header'>
          <h2>ReactJS Notes App</h2>
          <button><i className="fas fa-plus-circle" onClick = {this.handleClick}></i></button>
        </div>

        <Note />

        {this.state.notesArr.map((x, key) => (<Note />))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I expect the auto resize to always work whenever the Note component is rendered from the map.

Comment: I Think shouldComponentUpdate() will good for this-

Answer (score 1):

You should use `refs` to access real DOM element properties - read [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

You don't need these type of event handling - read [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Event handler usually uses `setState()` forcing component to rerender (`render()` call).

Search for some react TODO project/tutorial to not reinvent the wheel and learn react patterns.

Comment: Please can you be more specific. Mention the areas in my code that need these changes. Thanks

Comment: too many things, whole `componentDidMount` f.e. this `querySelector` won't work for multiple `<Note />` instances - learn basic react patterns first, really.

Comment: Okay. I appreciate